# Can you please check if my calculation below is correct. How can i simplify $\exp(e^t)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Can you please check if my calculation below is correct? How can I simplify $e^{e^t}$?

Comment: The only thing I see a problem with is that after you integrated, you didn't have a constant of integration. $\ln|x|=e^t+C$ and so $x=e^{e^t+C}=e^{e^t}e^C=e^{e^t}K=Ke^{e^t}$

Comment: You don't need to simplify it.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i integrate the equation below and simplify exp(e^t)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221604/how-can-i-integrate-the-equation-below-and-simplify-expet)

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me, *except* remember to include the arbitrary constant when integrating.

Also, you cannot simply $\exp(e^t)$ any futher. It is fine to just let it be.

Oh, and as @randomgirl points out in the comment, it should be $\ln|x|$ and not $\ln(x)$, unless you know that $x$ is a positive function.

Comment: what will be 1/x then?

Comment: If $x=K e^{e^t}$ then $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{K e^{e^t}}$ . But why are you looking for the reciprocal of $x$?

Answer (score 2):

From
$$
\frac{dX}{X}=e^t dt
$$ you rather get, for some constant $C$:
$$
\log \left| \frac{X}{C}\right|=e^t
$$ giving
$$
X=Ce^{\large e^t}.
$$

Comment: what will be 1/x then?

Comment: @GoitomHasa $\frac 1 X = \frac 1 C e^{-e^t}$.

Answer (score 0):

Besides having to include the constant, it's correct as:

$x = e^{e^t} \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt} = (e^t)*e^{e^t} = e^t * x$

Comment: what will be 1/x then?